# In Rails generating dynamic meta tags based on array of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following data about books.

```
[{
  title: "Gulliver's Travels",
  description: "Pretentious guy travels around a lot in Victorian England. Decides he doesn't like people.",
  image: 'someguy.jpg',
  name: 'gtravels'
 },
 {
  title: "Wizard of Oz",
  description: "Little girl travels to another dimension, commits murder, overthrows the patriarchy, and brings her dog",
  image: 'anarchydoro.jpg',
  name: 'dtravels'
  }]
```

I went ahead and created the following for my controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @books = Book.all
   @header = true
  end

  def order
   @book = Book.all
  end

  def show
   @book = Book.find(params[:id])
   @header = true
  end
```

I'm generating a web page for each individual book (show), page with all books (index), and a page for ordering based on all books (order). Cool. I also want the ability to share the data through social media so I created a partial view to handle all the meta tags for all the views (yay DRY) but it's failing.

So in my layouts/books I have:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Books</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
            <%= yield :head %>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <%= render partial: '/layouts/analytics' %>
                    <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
                        <%= render partial: '/books/metabooks'%>
```

In the partial I have:

```
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:title" content="I like big books" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:description" content="<%= books.description %>" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:url" content="<%=request.original_url%>" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="og:image" content="<%= @books.image %>" />


<!-- twitter meta tags -->
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" name="twitter:site" content="@bookguy" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" name="twitter:domain" content="@bookguy" />
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" name="twitter:url" content="<%=request.original_url%>">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" name="twitter:title" content="<%= @books.title %>">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" name="twitter:description" content="<%= @books.description %>">
<meta prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" property="twitter:image" content="<%= @books.image %>" />
```

I keep getting the following:
undefined method `description' for #Book::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007faab4063568>

Then it hit me that I'm trying to pass an array through. So how do I make the meta tags dynamic based on the url?

Comment: In the partial you refer to "books.description" and then "@books.image" (with and without @). Moreover. Aren't you referring to one book? (book.description; book.image, book.title, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how I solved it for me really isn't an exact answer to the question posed of creating a dynamic meta tags. I generated a partial specifically for the show and then another partial for the index and order.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Books</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= yield :head %>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <%= render partial: '/layouts/analytics' %>
                <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
                   <% @metabook == true %>
                    <%= render partial: '/books/metabooks'%>
                      <% end %>
```